# Office Add In Memory Limit

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, ms-office, vsto

I am developing a set of Office add ins that reads and writes templates and other files from a locally stored serialized object. Until now it has been going well, however, since I have been stress testing it by writing big amounts of data to this local object, and loading it into memory when reading from it, I have been getting SystemOutOfMemory exceptions. I do clean memory out each time I am done with this object, but simply loading it into memory can cause the exception be thrown.

The object is at most 100mb in size at any given time, so there is no way that it is using all the desktop resources to load this object into memory, so I have been wondering whether it may be that Microsoft limits the amount of memory that an add in may use.

What I would like to know is of anyone knows if there is a size limit and what it may be, as well as how to increase it if there is a limit present?

Thank you in advance for any advice given.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code of the class that I am serializing:

```vb
Imports System.Environment
Imports Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<Serializable()> _
Public Class LocalDBObject
Private aOfficesDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private aFieldDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private aSectorsDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private aDocumentsDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private aLibraryDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private aRolesDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private aSettings As mySettings = New mySettings()
Private aUpdateDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Private aUser As UserInfo = New UserInfo()
Private aDistributionFilesDS As DataSet = New DataSet()

Public Property UpdateDate() As DateTime
    Get
        UpdateDate = aUpdateDate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DateTime)
        aUpdateDate = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Settings() As mySettings
    Get
        Settings = aSettings
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As mySettings)
        aSettings = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property RolesDS() As DataSet
    Get
        RolesDS = aRolesDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aRolesDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property UserInfo() As UserInfo
    Get
        UserInfo = aUser
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As UserInfo)
        aUser = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Userfolder As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\CIM\" + Environment.UserName

Public Shared UserDistributionfolder As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\CIM\CIM Distribution Files"

Public Shared Function CheckFile() As Boolean
     Return System.IO.File.Exists(Userfolder + "\LocalDB.dat")
End Function

Public Shared Sub Write(ByVal obj As LocalDBObject)
    Serializer.Serialize2(obj, Userfolder + "\LocalDB.dat")
End Sub

Public Shared Function Read() As LocalDBObject
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Userfolder) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Userfolder)
    End If

    Dim obj As LocalDBObject = Serializer.deSerialize2(Userfolder + "\LocalDB.dat")

    Return obj
End Function

Public Property DocumentsDS() As DataSet
    Get
        DocumentsDS = aDocumentsDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aDocumentsDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LibraryDS() As DataSet
    Get
        LibraryDS = aLibraryDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aLibraryDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property OfficesDS() As DataSet
    Get
        OfficesDS = aOfficesDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aOfficesDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property FieldDS() As DataSet
    Get
        FieldDS = aFieldDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aFieldDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SectorsDS() As DataSet
    Get
        SectorsDS = aSectorsDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aSectorsDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property DistributionDS() As DataSet
    Get
        DistributionDS = aDistributionFilesDS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataSet)
        aDistributionFilesDS = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Function GetNameForLibaryGroup(ByVal FieldID As Integer, ByVal obj As LocalDBObject) As String
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.aFieldDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If dr("FieldID") = FieldID Then
            Return dr("FieldName")
        End If
    Next
    Return ""
End Function

Public Shared Function GetFileForTemplate(ByVal DocID As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.DocumentsDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Try
                Dim data As Byte() = CType(dr("docdata"), Byte())
                Return data
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End If

    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Shared Function GetFilenameForTemplate(ByVal DocID As Integer) As String
    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.DocumentsDS.Tables(0).Rows()
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Return Convert.ToString(LocalDBObject.Userfolder + "\" + dr("docName")) + "_" + Convert.ToString(dr("DocID")) + "." + Convert.ToString(dr("docext")).Substring(1)
        End If
    Next
    Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".txt"
End Function
Public Shared Function GetFilenameOnlyForTemplate(ByVal DocID As Integer) As String

    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.DocumentsDS.Tables(0).Rows()
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Return Convert.ToString(dr("docName")) + "." + Convert.ToString(dr("docext")).Substring(1)
        End If

    Next
    Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".txt"
End Function

Public Shared Function GetFilenameForPicture(ByVal DocID As Integer) As String

    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.DocumentsDS.Tables(0).Rows()
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Return Convert.ToString(LocalDBObject.Userfolder + "\" + dr("docName")) + "." + Convert.ToString(dr("docext")).Substring(1)
        End If

    Next
    Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".txt"
End Function

Public Shared Function GetFileForLibrary(ByVal DocID As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.LibraryDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Try
                Dim data As Byte() = CType(dr("docdata"), Byte())
                Return data
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End If

    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Shared Function GetFileLibaryDate(ByVal DocID As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.LibraryDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Try
                Dim adate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr("docdateupdated"))
                Return adate
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100)
            End Try
        End If

    Next
    Return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetFilenameForLibary(ByVal DocID As Integer) As String

    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each dr As DataRow In obj.LibraryDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If dr("docid") = DocID Then
            Return Convert.ToString(LocalDBObject.Userfolder + "\" + dr("docName")) + "_" + Convert.ToString(dr("DocID")) + "." + Convert.ToString(dr("docext")).Substring(1)
        End If

    Next
    Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".txt"
End Function

'EUGENE: Added this to get the distribution folders.
Public Shared Function GetDistributionFileDS() As List(Of Integer)
    Dim LocalDocIDList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    If obj.aDistributionFilesDS.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Row As DataRow In obj.aDistributionFilesDS.Tables(0).Rows
            LocalDocIDList.Add(Row("docid"))
        Next
    End If
    Return LocalDocIDList
End Function

Public Shared Function GetDistributionFilePath(DocumentID As Integer) As String
    Dim LocalDocumentPath As String = ""

    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each Row As DataRow In obj.aDistributionFilesDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If Row("docid") = DocumentID Then
            LocalDocumentPath = LocalDBObject.UserDistributionfolder + "\" + CStr(Row("docid")) + "-" + CStr(Row("docName")) + CStr(Row("docext"))
        End If
    Next

    Return LocalDocumentPath
End Function

Public Shared Function GetDistributionFileData(DocumentID As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim LocalDocumentData As Byte() = Nothing

    Dim obj As CIMShared.LocalDBObject = CIMShared.LocalDBObject.Read()
    For Each Row As DataRow In obj.aDistributionFilesDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If Row("docid") = DocumentID Then
            LocalDocumentData = CType(Row("docdata"), Byte())
        End If
    Next

    Return LocalDocumentData
End Function
End Class
```

Here are the serializer functions that serializes the class, and that deserilizes the class.

```vb
Public Shared Sub Serialize(ByVal obj As LocalDBObject, ByVal FileName As String)
    Dim Stream As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(Stream)
    Dim x As New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)
    x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, obj)
    objStreamWriter.Close()
End Sub

Public Shared Function deSerialize(ByVal FileName As String) As LocalDBObject
    Dim obj As New LocalDBObject()
    Dim Stream As FileStream
    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
    Try
        Stream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)

        objStreamReader = New StreamReader(Stream)

        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)
        obj = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
        objStreamReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = New LocalDBObject()
        Try
            Stream.Close()
        Catch

        End Try
        Try
            objStreamReader.Close()
        Catch

        End Try
    End Try
    Return obj
End Function
```

**NOTE:** I realize this is not the cleanest or neatest code, this is a former colleagues code that I am using and trying to resolve bugs on.

What is currently happening is that every time I de-serialize the class, which is about 300MB in size, I get a Out Of Memory Exception. In no way is this using all the computer memory, hence why I would like to find out if there is a memory usage limit on Microsoft Office add-ins?

Answer (score 0):

What object are you talking about? Could you be more specific?

Anyway, I always suggest releasing underlying COM objects insteatly. Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject to release an Office object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Comment: Hi Eugene, its a custom class which I XML serialize to save certain user configurations to it, as well as template and other file data. The customer I have developed this for had requested the ability to save template packages, and these can be quite large, and hence this XML file can become large-ish to load into memory.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are doing in the code and what part of the code causes the issue.